# Which Shimano Freehubs can I use on the WH-R550 wheel?

Tags: shimano, freehub, road

Looking to replace the freehub on a Shimano WH-R550. The Shimano parts line-up is a total mess. No LBS has been able to give any accurate info. Basically question is, which freehubs can I use on the WH-R550 wheel? The pool of possibilities being (FH-5500, FH-5501, FH-6500, M7XX-XT) etc. The reason for doing this is to replace the freehub with a better quality one and to keep options open as I will unlikely source the exact same one used in the wheel.

Looking to replace freehub body only, not the entire hub and shell.

Comment: The question might be more readable without the misleading whole hub models and mountain bike tag

Comment: @user Welcome to the site - you might like to please take a moment to browse the [tour]  The question and answers are always up for improvement and clarification where appropriate, and that is built-into the stackexchange structure.  Comments are ephemeral and exist only as long as needed.  Different SE sites might vary subtly, but they're all similar in overall design.

Answer (score 10):

Shimano provides good official guidance about what the right part is and no guidance about what can be substituted. From the publically available [exploded view diagram](https://si.shimano.com/en/pdfs/ev/WH-R550-R-2337/EV-WH-R550-R-2337C.pdf) we know the matching part is Y-4C4 98090. The wheel is old and this part is not available new, but it's possible you could find an NOS one.

If you can't source that part, the task is to find a different FHB that fits the shell and can have a collection of compatible drive-side axle hardware assembled that keeps you at 130. Since it's an old wheel that's already worn through its original FHB, there is often little merit in trying to reuse the original DS cone. This wheel uses the most common type of Shimano shell to FHB attachment splines so there are many that physically fit on the shell.

All 8/9/10 Shimano hubs, 130 or 135, have the same basic impetus to not waste any space between the DS flange and the DS locknut. Therefore any new FHB you get along with its matching collection of cone, spacer, seals, and locknut is likely to have you land back at 130 or very close. Where you can get into the weeds is if you try replacing just the FHB but not the rest of it, because the sealing elements won't work as intended if there's a mismatch, and there may be other dimensional differences as well in terms of where the balls are inside the FHB. In many cases you can transplant the old pressed-in FHB seal into a new and re-use the DS axle hardware that way, but it's not as guaranteed to work and again there is often a lot of merit in starting with a fresh cone anyway.

The world is not short of Shimano-hubbed 9 and 10 speed road wheels with the same freehub mounting type that died by violence rather than hub wear (smashed rim etc). Shops throw them away whole all the time, especially if they're Tiagra-ish or below. A good plan in a case like this is get one of those and transplant the freehub and all the DS axle hardware.

Whenever you do the above, assume you'll need to make a minor correction to the wheel dish. Usually it's pretty negligible.

Comment: @user If you want to know which freehubs if any are cross-compatible in the literal drop-in replacement sense, the only way to get that information is look through all the EV documents for all the rear hubs and wheels and find ones that take the same collection of cone and right side axle hardware. That's not practical and there is no magical Shimano freehub body interchangeability table to be found somewhere if one digs deep enough. Above is an expedient and practical approach to getting back to something that works.